# ZPL Label Length

Tags: c#, zebra-printers, zpl

How can I zpl.label_length to fit the size of the content being printed?

The content that I print is variable number of lines so there's no way I can know in advance how long I need the label to be.

Comment: you need read more zpl and even the printer's documents. they might tell you how to calculate the size of text of specific font. or, you just generate the whole label as an image. then print that image.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in continuous mode the idea is to not think of your whole print job as one format. Print your header as a format. Then print each line as a format. When you have printed all of your lines print your footer as a format.